# How do i call shortcode value from dashboard editor?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have used shortcode like this:

```
<?php
    add_shortcode( 'myproduct', 'myproduct_func' );

    function myproduct_func( $atts ) {

        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'cols' => 'none',
            'data' => 'none',
        ), $atts ) );

        $cols = explode(',',$cols);
        $data = explode(',',$data);
        $total = count($cols);

        $output = "";
        foreach($cols as $col):
            $output .= "| {$col} ";
        endforeach;

        $output .= "<br>";

        $counter = 1;
        foreach($data as $datum):
            $output .= "| {$datum} ";
            if($counter%$total==0):
                $output .= "<br>";
            endif;
            $counter++;
        endforeach;

        return $output;

    }

    ?>
```

Do display the shortcode when I write the code :

> echo do_shortcode('[myproduct cols="name,quantity,price"
>   data="name1,5,2.00,name2,3,3.25"]');

In index.php it display table on my home page but:

Same code [myproduct cols="name,quantity,price" data="name1,5,2.00,name2,3,3.25"] when I write in my home page dashboard editor, it shows nothing on my home page. I want the value of cols and data is dynamic so it should be passed through dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing this in the **visual** or the **text** editor? For Shortcodes to work must be on the text editor in the tinymce on the right tabs.

[image]

Also you must include your myproduct_func in functions.php so it's available.